# How to use references within equations and refstyle?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

The `refstyle` package seems to break references within equations

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{refstyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \label{enu:test}
\end{enumerate}

$\eqref{enu:test}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is what it looks like without `resfstyle`:

[image]

Comment: `\eqref` doesn't usually need to be within math.  Also, the file needs to be processed twice for the reference number to become available,.

Comment: It does not matter how often I process it, it still looks like that. Also, I would like to have the reference within math. This is no problem if I remove `refstyle`. (I have added another image.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, I need to do this manually:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{refstyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \label{enu:test}
\end{enumerate}

$(\ref{enu:test})$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `\eqref` a prefix `eq:` is automatically added to the label. If you want to use it

1. the label must start with `eq:`
2. the prefix must be left out when referencing

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refstyle}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \label{eq:test}
\end{enumerate}

$\eqref{test}$

\eqref{test}

\end{document}
```

(are you sure it is a good idea to use `\eqref` for something that is not an equation?)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this does not have the right result either. It says still "equation (...)". Unfortunately, I omitted that I use the amsmath package. I have added it to my question and if you remove the `refstyle` package, then you can see that it works well.

Comment: @Daniel Well, of course it says "equation (...)" because `\eqref` is for referencing equations. If the object you are referencing is not an equation, simply don't use `\eqref`

Comment: That's not true in the case you use amsmath package, as I suggested. Maybe try my modified example with removed `refstyle` package to see what I mean.